# Can WeavingURLClassLoader only weave aspects of local jars?

Tags: java, reflection, applet, aspectj

I try to use AspectJ loadtime-weaving in an applet with jars from my web server as I use a Java reflection call on a library. The name of the class that must be loaded is passed as a parameter. I cannot use compiletime-weaving therefore.
Here is some piece of code of my applet "MyApplet":

```
URLClassLoader appletClassLoader = (URLClassLoader)
RemoteConfigurationApplet.class.getClassLoader();
URL[] urlList = appletClassLoader.getURLs();
URL aspectJar = null;
try {
     aspectJar = new URL("https://myserver:8443/MyWebApp/applet/MyApplet.jar/");
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
WeavingURLClassLoader weavingClassLoader = new WeavingURLClassLoader(urlList, 
    new URL[]{ aspectJar }, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

However, I always get an exception:

```
org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: bad aspect library: "/MyWebApp/applet/MyApplet.jar"
```

I suspect the usage of a file-object in "addAspectLibrary" to be responsible for the problem:

```
private void addAspectLibrary(String aspectLibraryName) {
    File aspectLibrary = new File(aspectLibraryName);
    if (aspectLibrary.isDirectory() || (FileUtil.isZipFile(aspectLibrary))) {
        try {
            info("adding aspect library: '" + aspectLibrary + "'");
            weaver.addLibraryJarFile(aspectLibrary);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            error("exception adding aspect library: '" + ex + "'");
        }
    } else {
        error("bad aspect library: '" + aspectLibrary + "'");
    }
}
```

It cuts down the URL and then looks on the harddisk for this file where it cannot find it.
Has anybody a solution to make it running though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in AspectJ and raised one in [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409613).

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure whether to consider it as a bug.